# Websocket nativo em HTML5

Tags: html5

Nas estações de PCs que pretendo utilizar um conjunto de paginas HTML5 para comunicar dados, está bloqueado a instalação de software, mas permite adição de arquivos. Onde encontro um pacote de websocket, fácil de implementar e simples, não exigindo instalação e também liberação de endereços externos (exceto IP do mestre e escravo)

Comment: O cliente de WebSocket é "nativo" do próprio browser, não precisa de "pacote" nenhum. Qualquer arquivo JS tem acesso a WebSockets em browsers modernos. Só do lado de servidor que precisa rodar algo especial para isso, independente de instalar ou não.

Comment: Eu não sei se entendi direito a sua pergunta, você quer fazer requisições a servidores de terceiro no lado cliente da sua aplicação?